# $f\times f'$ is a regular epi if $f,f'$ are regular epis

Tags: category-theory

Let $f:a\to b$ and $f':a'\to b'$ be regular epimorphisms; to show that $f\times f'$ is a regular epimorphism, it is sufficient to prove that $f\times 1_{a'}$ and $1_b\times f'$ are regular epimorphisms.

Suppose that $f$ is the coequalizer of two arrows $g,g':c\to a$; the only way that I see to obtain two arrows in $a\times a'$ is with $g\times 1_{a'}$ and $g'\times 1_{a'}$. However I have no idea on how to prove that, if $h:b\times a'\to d$ is such that $h(g\times 1_{a'})=h(g'\times 1_{a'})$, then $h$ factors through $f\times 1_{a'}$. The issue is that I mostly have arrows with a product as a domain (and not codomain), so I don't see what property I could use. Would you give me a suggestion? Thank you

Comment: How hard this proof is might depend on the assumptions on the base category where $f,f'$ live (in particular, whenever each $a\times-$ preserves colimits, the proof is very simple). So, what *exactly* is the statement you're after?

Comment: @fosco the exercise left by the teacher consisted just of the title of my question; the lecture was about regular categories, so maybe the base category is regular, but I don't know if in a regular category the product functor preserves colimits (but perhaps you were thinking to a cartesian closed category)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$A back-of-the-envelope-y computation seems to say that the square

$$
\begin{CD}
A\times A' @>\pi_A>> A \\ 
@Vf\times A'VV @VVfV\\
B\times A' @>>\pi_P> B
\end{CD}
$$ is a pullback; the claim then follows from the fact that the ambient category is regular, because regular epis are stable under pullback; regularity in this sense is an exactness condition on the ambient category, stated in terms of a nice interaction between limits and colimits (but note that more in general, what you show in this way is that if $\cal E$ is a pullback stable class of epimorphisms in any category $\bf C$, then $f\times f'\in\cal E$ for every $f,f'\in\cal E$).